# Babel - Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, openid-connect

I'm trying to use [`oidc-client`](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library in my React project but run into the same error everytime I run the code :

> `Babel - Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined`

I know that there's a specific [Redux implementation](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc) of this library but I've had the same issue so I'm taking a step back. I'll use the Redux implemenation once my issue is fixed.

I've pulled the [`redux-oidc-example`](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc-example) code and I'm running both at the same time, trying to find what makes it break. The results I've had so far are :

- Webpack configs are the same (mostly)
- All "important" dependencies are the same, with the same version.

At this point I'm trying to align **every** dependencies to see if one of them is responsible but I'd welcome any idea.

**EDIT after @MinusFour comment :** running `npm ls buffer` produce the following :

```
├─┬ styled-components@2.1.2
│ └── buffer@5.0.7 
└─┬ webpack@2.7.0
  └─┬ node-libs-browser@2.0.0
    └── buffer@4.9.1
```

Comment: Do `npm ls buffer` in your project root, does it has a listing? Maybe you had browserify installed before or something?

Comment: @MinusFour I've edited the question with the result

Comment: So, I've downloaded the package and build it myself and it's not including `feross/buffer` polyfill at all. How are you using it? Are you using the files in the `dist` directory? The package might just have a bogus build or something...

Comment: I'm not using buffer nor does oidc-client. Not directly at least. I believe that webpack is going to include it automatically while building. Or something like that

Comment: It's not using it directly, the module `jsrsasign` is using node `buffer` module and `oidc-client` webpack config is polyfilling it with `feros/buffer`, as to why is it not a valid polyfill. I think that's the better question... You can disable it if you build `oidc-client` with `Buffer : false` in the `node` key of webpack. But like I said, it'd be better to find out the problem on the polyfill. If you could provide the exact line where it throws the error maybe I can check it out.

Comment: After looking at the webpack build for `oidc-client` the only thing I could think of is that `global` binding is not working for your environment. It should work for the browser as it is (if you don't have it under strict mode somehow).

Comment: Good point. I'll investigate this. I'm considering other solutions at the moment as I have to get this done. Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a week worth of investigation (thanks to @MinusFour for setting me on the right path), It appears that it was a Webpack loader issue.

In the `babel-loader` configuration, you need to exclude node_modules in a very peculiar way. `redux-oidc-example` does it by using a regex and I was using an array of strings.

If you want to be compliant with Webpack convention and use an array of String, you can exclude nodes_modules this way :

```
exclude: [
    path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules'),
    // ... other exclusions
]
```

Comment: still doesn't work when the script is loaded via `<script type="module"...`

Comment: Getting the same issue with <script type="module". Any luck on that one?